# RangeError: Invalid string length usando JSZIP

Tags: javascript

A funcionalidade da minha aplicação é fazer upload de arquivos zip, dentro de cada arquivo zip tem arquivos **XML**, no processo ele tem que descompactar o arquivo e em seguida ele salva os dados no banco de dados, a aplicação consegui fazer o upload de arquivos pequenos com 150 megas, mas não consegue fazer upload de arquivos com 4 Gigas, a mensagem que dar é o estouro de memoria;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dar uma olhada aqui também;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que pesquisei na internet no algoritmo javascript precisaria conseguir dividir o processo para não sobrecarregar a aplicação, saber a solução é fácil, difícil e colocar em prática, dar uma olhada no algoritmo javascript que faz o upload de arquivos zip.

```
async function handleFile(data, selecao) {
        var f = data.files[0];
        var valido = true;

        var r  = new Array();
        r ["Cargo.xml"] = 0,
        r ["ClasseNivelFaixa.xml"] = 0,
        r ["CodigoVantagemDesconto.xml"] = 0,
        r ["Dependente.xml"] = 0,
        r ["FolhaPagamento.xml"] = 0,
        r ["HistoricoFuncional.xml"] = 0,
        r ["Lotacao.xml"] = 0,
        r ["Servidor.xml"] = 0,
        r ["VantagemDesconto.xml"] = 0,
        r ["Vinculo.xml"]  = 0;
        r ["undefined"]  = 0;

        var dateBefore = new Date();
        var jsZipInstance = new JSZip();

        await jsZipInstance.loadAsync(f)                                   // 1) read the Blob
        .then(function(zip) {
            var dateAfter = new Date();

                zip.forEach(function (relativePath, zipEntry) {  // 2) print entries
                    if (typeof r[zipEntry.name] !== 'undefined'){
                        r [zipEntry.name] = r [zipEntry.name] + 1;          
                    }else{
                        r ["undefined"]  = r ["undefined"] + 1;
                    }

                });

                var conteudoIncompativel = false || r ["undefined"] > 0;

                if (!conteudoIncompativel){
                    for (x in r){
                        if (r[x] != 1 && x != "undefined" ){
                            conteudoIncompativel = true;
                            break;  
                        } 
                    }
                }

                if (conteudoIncompativel){
                    var mensagem = "${codigoMensagem.get('1003')}";
                    insereBotoes(mensagem, new Date());
                    $("#myModal .modal-title").text("Gerar PDF com erros encontrados");
                    $("#myModal .modal-body").html(mensagem);
                    $("#myModal").modal("show");    
                    valido = false; 
                }

        }, function (e) {
            insereBotoes("${codigoMensagem.get('1004')}", new Date());
            $("#myModal .modal-title").text("Gerar PDF com erros encontrados");
            $("#myModal .modal-body").text("${codigoMensagem.get('1004')}");
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
            valido = false;
        });

        var teste = "";
        var quantidadeVazio = 0;

        if (valido){
            for (x in r){


//              try {
                    if (x != "undefined"){//uint8array, arraybuffer
                        await jsZipInstance.file(x).async("string").then(function (data) {

                            console.log(data);

                          var itemComp = x == "FolhaPagamento.xml" ? "ItemFolha" : "Item" + x.substr(0, x.length - 4);  
                          if (data.indexOf(itemComp) == -1){
                            quantidadeVazio ++; 
                          }

                          if (data.length == 0){
                              valido = false;
                              teste = x;
                          }

                        });

                        if (teste.length > 0){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
//              }catch(err) {
//                  console.log(err.message)
//              }

            }

            if (teste.length > 0){
                insereBotoes("${codigoMensagem.get('1009')}".replace("{0}", teste), new Date());
                $("#myModal .modal-title").text("Gerar PDF com erros encontrados");
                $("#myModal .modal-body").text("${codigoMensagem.get('1009')}".replace("{0}", teste));
                $("#myModal").modal("show");
            } else if (quantidadeVazio == 10){
                insereBotoes("${codigoMensagem.get('1011')}".replace("{0}", teste), new Date());
                $("#myModal .modal-title").text("Gerar PDF com erros encontrados");
                $("#myModal .modal-body").text("${codigoMensagem.get('1011')}");
                $("#myModal").modal("show");
                valido = false;
            }
        }    
       return valido;       
    }
```

Alguém teria uma ideia de como poderia refatorar o código para ele dividir o processo do upload de arquivos?

Comment: Você. usou método errado. `var r = new Array()` variável r só aceita array e não objeto.

Comment: Tudo bem Maury, se você acha que esse é o problema, por favor como eu poderia fazer?

Comment: É inútil usar `new Array()` porque não usar `{}` ou `[]`. Isso menos código a sua script.

Comment: Tudo bem @MauryDeveloper eu já entendi que você tinha informado que não estava certo,  por favor você teria ideia de como eu poderia modificar meu código ou você quer dizer que o meu algoritmo está todo errado por causa disso?

Comment: So mudar variável r para `var r = [];`. Você poderia me manda os links das dependencia(jQuery,JSZIP).

Comment: Com a sua sugestão gerou um erro, e impediu de arquivos de 3 megas conseguir processa, que antes processava.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96027/discussion-between-maury-developer-and-wladyband).